# How to solve this infinite family of equations?

Tags: symbolic

Is there any way to do a problem like this with MMa?  I have an infinte set of coupled equations.  j is a real integer index where $-\infty<j<\infty$. {a,b,c,d,f} are variables, and K's are constants.  I need to find closed form solutions for $\{a_{j},b_{j},c_{j}\}$ in terms of the K's. I believe the respective solutions for $\{a_{j},b_{j},c_{j}\}$ should have the same form for all j.

$$a_{j}+b_{j}+c_{j}=K_{j}$$

$$3a_{j}+2b_{j}+c_{j}=c_{j+1}$$

$$6a_{j}+3b_{j}+d_{j}+3f_{j}=0$$

$$3a_{j}+2b_{j}+d_{j}+2f_{j}=0$$

$$d_{j}+f_{j}-f_{j-1}=0$$

Comment: The usual command for this would be `RSolve`.  However, `RSolve[{a[j] + b[j] + c[j] == k[j], 3 a[j] + 2 b[j] + c[j] == c[j + 1], 6 a[j] + 3 b[j] + d[j] + 3 f[j] == 0, 3 a[j] + 2 b[j] + d[j] + 2 f[j] == 0, d[j] + f[j] - f[j - 1] == 0}, {a[j], b[j], c[j], d[j], f[j]}, j]` does not return a result.  Replacing `k[j]` with an explicit number (like `0` or `1`) does return a result in terms of two unknown constants, so you may need to provide more information about the form of $K_j$ and/or the initial values of some of the variables.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  Well, that's the thing, the K's are arbitrary constants, infinitely many of them.  That's why I need all the variables in terms of the K's.  However, I do expect the coupling of K_n to {a,b,c,d,f}_m to be largest when n~m and diminish when |m-n|>>0.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

(Format[#[n_]] := Subscript[#, n]) & /@ {a, b, c, d, f, k};

eqns = {
   a[j] + b[j] + c[j] == k[j],
   3 a[j] + 2 b[j] + c[j] == c[j + 1],
   6 a[j] + 3 b[j] + d[j] + 3 f[j] == 0,
   3 a[j] + 2 b[j] + d[j] + 2 f[j] == 0,
   d[j] + f[j] - f[j - 1] == 0};
```

Excluding the difference equations

```
sol1 = Solve[eqns[[{1, 3, 4}]], {a[j], b[j], d[j]}][[1]] // Simplify
```

[image]

The difference equations are then

```
eqns2 = eqns[[{2, 5}]] /. sol1 // Simplify
```

[image]

Using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to solve the difference equations

```
sol2 = RSolve[eqns2, {c, f}, j][[1]]
```

[image]

The solutions for `{a, b, c}` in terms of the `k` are

```
sol3 = Append[(Most@sol1) /. sol2, c[j] -> (c[j] /. sol2)] // 
  Simplify
```

[image]

Setting the arbitrary constants to zero

```
sol3m = sol3 /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0} // Simplify
```

[image]

Since the indices for the sums run from `-1` to `j - 1`, the sums for `j < 0` are zero. Consequently, for `j < 0`

```
ConditionalExpression[sol3 /. Sum[_, _] :> 0 // Simplify, j < 0]
```

[image]

And for `j < 0` and the arbitrary constants set to zero

```
ConditionalExpression[sol3m /. Sum[_, _] :> 0 // Simplify, j < 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @BobHanlon , if you don't omitt the d[j] in sol3 `sol3 = Append[(sol1) /. sol2, c[j] -> (c[j] /. sol2)] // Simplify `   and `sol3m = sol3 /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> 0} // Simplify // Flatten `  a test of the equations `Table[eqns /. sol3m, {j, -5, 5}] // Simplify // TableForm ` says, all k[j] for j<0 have to be zero.